# Adding leaderboards and achievements to my app using android studio

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, android-sqlite

Need help for my App. I'm using android studio and i created an English tutorial. For my lessons i use a sqlite database then i put it in my assets folder then i use my database for my lessons list and i use a listview. For example if i click the noun or pronoun in listview it will proceed to the lesson for it whether or not he/she has read the lesson. As long as he visits or views the lesson's discussion it will add a percentage in the achievements but it will not add again - just once per topic.

Comment: What is the problem that you have that you want resolving?

Comment: hmm I want to add an achievements and leaderboards in my application in android studio...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help